# calculate an area based on x and y coordinates and width and height values in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have this problem I've been trying to solve by myself without any success.

I have an object to represent a rectangle, with it's position (x,y) and its size (width and height).

I have 2 lists, both contains the object mentioned before, one list represents the positive areas and the other represents the negative areas.

Based in this information, I need to get the total area that results if we add up all the elements in both positive and negative lists. I'm only interested in the result if the total area is a rectangle, otherwise it's irrelevant for me.

For example:
If the positive list contains these 2 objects

> {x:20, y:20, width:100, height:20}
> {x:20, y:40, width:80, height:80}

and the negative list contains this object

> {x:100, y:20, width:20, height:20}

The result of adding these 3 objects would be:

> {x:20, y:20, width:80, height:100}

This image shows the graphical representation of the 3 objects in those 2 lists and the result.

[image: example]

I appreciate any help you could bring.

edit: I made a small correction in one of the 3 objects, and the coordinate system I'm using is cartesian system with reversed y-axis (as you can see in the next figure)
[image: reversedYaxis]

Comment: _"result of adding these 3 objects would be"_ ? How ?

Comment: what coordinate system are you using? Shouldn't the taller rectangle be above the shorter one if y(tall) is 40 and y(short) is 20? Also shouldn't the negative rectangle start at x: 100 if it is matching your diagram as the short rectangle would span from 20 to 120 if it has a width of 100. That aside it is an interesting problem. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I must be missing something because this seems incredibly simple.

Comment: @Damon Thanks for your comments and for your time. Nop, the problem is not simple, and yes, I'm sorry I forgot to mention. The coordinate system I'm using is cartesian coordinates with y-axis reversed. I did made a mistake, the negative rectangle should have started at x:100 as you stated, I just fixed that. I tried mixing positive and negative rectangles to obtain a new set of rectangles, but I failed and it made things more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a simple question, and is more an algorithmic problem than a JavaScript problem.

This works with your example.

```js
var pos = [{x:20, y:20, width:100, height:20}, {x:20, y:40, width:80, height:80}];
var neg = [{x:100, y:20, width:20, height:20}]; // Fixed it x: 80 -> x: 100

// Create one single array of rectangles and add an attribute indicating if
// a rectangle is neg or pos
var rects =  pos.map(function(o){
  return Object.assign({pos: true}, o);
}).concat(neg.map(function(o){
  return Object.assign({pos: false}, o);
}));



// Combine two rectangles.
function combine2Rects(r1, r2, maintainOrder){
  // width addition
  if(r1.pos && r2.pos && r1.x === r2.x && r1.width === r2.width && r2.y === r1.y + r1.height){
    return Object.assign({}, r1, { height: r1.height + r2.height });

  // Height addition
  } else if(r1.pos && r2.pos && r1.y === r2.y && r2.x === r1.x + r1.width && r1.height === r2.height) {
    return Object.assign({}, r1, { width: r1.width + r2.width });

  // Height bottom subtraction
  } else if(r1.pos && !r2.pos && r1.x === r2.x && r1.width === r2.width && r2.y === r1.y + r1.height - r2.height && r1.height - r2.height > 0){
    return Object.assign({}, r1, { height: r1.height - r2.height });
    
  // Height top subtraction
  } else if(r1.pos && !r2.pos && r1.x === r2.x && r1.width === r2.width && r2.y === r1.y  && r1.height > r2.height){
    return Object.assign({}, r1, { height: r1.height - r2.height, y: r1.y + r2.height });
    
  // Width right subtraction
  } else if(r1.pos && !r2.pos && r1.y === r2.y && r1.height === r2.height && r2.x === r1.x + r1.width - r2.width && r1.width - r2.width > 0){
    return Object.assign({}, r1, { width: r1.width - r2.width });
    
  // Width left subtraction
  } else if(r1.pos && !r2.pos && r1.y === r2.y && r1.height === r2.height && r2.x === r1.x && r2.width < r1.width){
    return Object.assign({}, r1, { x: r1.x + r2.width, width: r1.width - r2.width });
    

  // If two negative rectangle, treat them as pos then invert them again.
  } else if(!r1.pos && !r2.pos){
    var invertedResult = combine2Rects(
      Object.assign({}, r1, { pos: true }),
      Object.assign({}, r2, { pos: true }),
      maintainOrder
    );
    if(invertedResult){
      invertedResult.pos = false;
      return invertedResult;
    }
  
  // try with r2 at the place of r1 and vice-versa
  } else if(!maintainOrder){
    return combine2Rects(r2, r1, true);
  }
}

function combineRects(rects){
  var lastN = 0;
  var result = rects.slice();
  // While we still made at least one combination
  debugger
  while(result.length !== lastN){
    lastN = result.length;
    // For each rectangle in the list
    for(var i=0; i<result.length; i++){
      var r1 = result[i];
      // Try to combine it with one of the following rectangles in the list
      for(var j=i+1; j<result.length; j++){
        var r2 = result[j];
        var c = combine2Rects(r1, r2);
        if(c){
          // replace the combined rectangle by the combination
          result[i] = c;
          // and remove the rectangle it has been combined with
          result.splice(j, 1);
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return result;
}

document.write(JSON.stringify(combineRects(rects)));
```

Comment: Interesting. I'll test it with something more complex and I'll tell you what happened. Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: Hi there, I tried with these values `pos=[{x:20,y:20,width:80,height:80},{x:100,y:20,width:25,height:25},{x:100,y:45,width:25,height:25}];`
 `neg=[{x:20,y:20,width:25,height:80},{x:45,y:20,width:80,height:25},{x:45,y:45,width:80,height:25}];` I was expecting `{x:45,y:70,width:55,height:30}` , that's not what I got.

Comment: I fixed a bug in the above code. However, this code only works if the result is a rectangle which does not seem to be the case with your last example. http://codepen.io/roque/pen/wGEaJp?editors=0010

Comment: Also there is complicated case where it won't work. But if you find you need them, I'll let you fix them.